# I need help using LIKE in mysql php , false returns all the time

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php page , which should search a string that is sent to it , in a column of a mysql table . 
the code is:

```
$search=$_POST['search'];
$search_result= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM my table WHERE title LIKE '.$search.'%');
```

the connection is ok but it return false all the time !

Comment: Echo out the SQL you're generating and run it in the database; it'll tell you what the problem is.

Comment: it is not LIKE but something else. You need to test your queries in console first

Comment: Its because LIKE requires a string input which you're not giving it change your overall query to use double quotes for its limiters " and single quotes around the like string ' so `"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '$search%'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is bad, it will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my table WHERE title LIKE foo%
```

When it should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM my table WHERE title LIKE 'foo%'
```

So change the line to:

```
$search_result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my table WHERE title LIKE '". $search ."%'");
```

Or simply:

```
$search_result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my table WHERE title LIKE '$search%'");
```

And, as always, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use PDO or MySQLi instead, blah, blah, the usual song and dance of the minions of the PHP tag.

Comment: thanks alot ! but i dont want it to find titles that have " abc " when i send  " ab " to it, what should i do?

Comment: @faridzs You'll either need to chain together some `AND NOT LIKE` statements, or get comfy with regular expressions and use something like `WHERE title RLIKE '^ab[^c]'`. [More info on RLIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double '%':

```
$search_result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my table WHERE title LIKE '%" . $search. "%'");
```

Also must be `LIKE '%criteria%'` your actual query is `LIKE %criteria%` (no quotes)

Comment: Do not use double percentages if you if you do not need to find a string that matches on either side. This really eats up resources, slowing down your application and adding a bigger load time for your users.

Comment: Of course, but he is searching on the title, so must be a blog like search.